# Chrome 64bit - CSS animation causes positioning bug

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hallo I am trying to create a button aligned to the right of the screen which leads to the next article.

Everything works as I want it, till the point when I add the css transition. 
As you can see in the fiddle I have twice the exact same code, except that the blue bar does have a css transition property and the green bar does not have a transition.

I am using the 64bit version of chrome (45.0.2453.0 dev-m) and while in here the green bar works as supposed when hovered, the content from the blue bar with the transition does have some major alignment bug. It seems that the content of the containers pops out of the containers.

```
<nav class="nav-next">
    <a href="link" class="link">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img width="100" height="100" src="http://travelwithoutplan.com/wp-content/uploads/DSC01985_Vibrance-100-200x200.jpg" class="attachment-100x100 wp-post-image" alt="DSC01985 Vibrance 100" />
        </div>
        <div class="headline">Travel Information for Liechtenstein</div>
    </a>
</nav>
```

CSS (without transition it works - but with transition it causes an alignment bug)

```
/*
.nav-next {
    -moz-transition: width .5s;
    -o-transition: width .5s;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s;
    transition: width .5s;
}
*/

.nav-next {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 120px;
}

.nav-next:hover {
    width: 330px;
}

.nav-next .headline:after, .nav-next .link {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
}

.nav-next .link {
    background: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c; 
    border-right: none;   
}

.nav-next:hover .link {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-next .link:before {
    color: #262626;
    left: auto;
    right: -23px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    content: "\e12e";
    font-family: wp-svg-plugin-icon-set1!important;
}

.nav-next .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.nav-next .headline {
    color: #595959;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 4px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-next .headline:after {
    content: "Next Article";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64g0vzq1/4/

[image: css transition error]

Here you can see how with Chrome 64bit-version (45.0.2453.0 dev-m) the aligment  of the content from the hovered blue bar (with css transition) is wrong. The text disappears behind the image, the image positionig is wrong etc. 
Below the content of the green bar (without css transition) is shown correctly.

Is this a css error or something? How can I fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, the fiddle works fine. There are not alignment issues as such with the current fiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the bug is. It's not clear from your post. Could you maybe take a screenshot and add it to the question? It appears to be working as designed for me.

Comment: Work fine for me on Firefox, Chrome and IE, what browser are you using?

Comment: I just checked and it seems to be a problem that only appears in Google Chrome.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the bug I am talking about.
Besides I am using the 64bit Version (45.0.2453.0 dev-m 64-bit), might it be just on this Version that the error occurs with?

Comment: why do you have 2 .nav-next?

Comment: My chrome is only on 43.0.2357.134 - are you using a beta version or test version? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: I do not actully have 2 .nav-next, this was just to show in comparison how one works and the other with css transition has an alignment error.

Comment: Yes it's the 64bit beta version I am using (https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html). I actuallly pretty much copied this next button from the CNN website but the weird thing is that on their website its working correctly for me with Chrome too. It's why I thought the problem must be my code.

Comment: My guess is that it is a probably with your beta version - I can't replicate the issue on stable chrome.

Comment: Yes I guess that's it. Good to know it's actually working on other normal browsers. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: I jumped onto the dev version you are using and recreated the bug. Interesting.

Comment: For completeness, the bug also occurs in a 32-bit canary (46.0.2457.0 canary). By the way, what is the E12E character supposed to look like? The browsers vary wildly in what they display there.

Comment: Nevermind the E12E character, it was just an arrow icon from a random css icon font I used on a website, which here gets replaced by the default browser icon for when the font character is missing. 
The interesting thing for me is that somehow on the CNN website they managed to fix that alignment bug also for the Chrome version I am using, I just couldn't figure out how.